# Why is insertBefore not working?

Tags: javascript, parent, addeventlistener, blur, appendchild

I have written the code shown below. I am trying to position the element "h45" above the "age". Somehow, it does not work and I get the following error : "The new child element contains the parent." Does anybody know why this happens and how I could fix it? I am new to JavaScript and I dont understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you all in advance!`

```js
var lastName=document.getElementById("lastName");
 var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName");
 var age= document.getElementById("alter")
 age.addEventListener("blur",showage,false);

function showage()
    {
        if (/[^0-9]/.test(age.value)) {
            
              var h45 = document.createElement("h4");
              var txttt = document.createTextNode("Bitte geben Sie nur Nummern ein");
              h45.appendChild(txttt);
              age.parentNode.appendChild(h45);
              h45.insertBefore(h45,age);
              h45.style.color = "red";
       
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The general syntax is `parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`. Now try and explain which one is which, when you write `h45.insertBefore(h45,age);`

Comment: basically, it looks like you are trying to insert h45 before himself...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this row

```
      h45.insertBefore(h45,age);
```

You should do something like:

```
      h45.parentNode.insertBefore(age, h45);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are inserting h45 inside h45

```
h45.insertBefore(h45,age);
```

insertBefore Syntax:

```
var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);
```

so your variable age is probably a div container representing an alert and you already have insert h45 inside age with this code line

```
age.parentNode.appendChild(h45);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `h45.insertBefore(h45,age);`
You cannot append the same element inside itself. It'll create cyclic dependency.

```
 h45.parentNode.insertBefore(age, h45);
```

See Fixed
https://plnkr.co/edit/EDkvssWMAcDV0enT2hL2?p=preview